Cannot convert undefined value to object - I am using react-native-draganddrop-board library
Check this screenshort
I've recently integrated the 'draganddropboard' library to implement functionality similar to Trello's drag-and-drop feature. However, I've encountered an issue where attempting to drag and drop a card results in an error stating 'cannot convert undefined value to object.' This problem occurred suddenly, despite the functionality working correctly previously. I'm unsure what caused this error to occur.
Please help guys. Need your support.
